# Benchmarking a simple hydrology module in R, Python, and Julia

Tags: python, r, julia, benchmarking

I started working recently with a team whose members variably prefer Python, R, and Julia (in order of popularity). We are translating a set of hydrology modules built by various team members into a common library and I want to do some basic benchmarking before coming to a consensus on which language we should choose for this purpose. The problem is that I'm pretty bad at Python and new to Julia, and I believe I may be biasing results due to poor coding practices.

The results for these modules (code below) are: Python (93 ms), R (55 ms), and Julia (0.5 ms). The code can't be vectorized (to my understanding), so I assumed Julia would be fastest but not by 100x, and I also assumed that Python would be faster than R.

Can anyone point out some basic errors in efficiency?

Python:

```
import numpy as np
def SM_routine_f(infiltration=None, PET=None, rcScl=0.1, rcExp=1.3, PETexp=2, Zr=1000, n=0.5, smhp=0.00, smwp=0.10, smfc=0.25, s0=0.5):
    nt = len(infiltration)
    SM_store = np.empty(nt+1)
    SM_store[0] = s0
    smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
    smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
    smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
    max_stor = Zr * n
    for i in range(nt):
        thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
        AET = np.where(thisSMstor > smhp_stor, (thisSMstor - smhp_stor) * PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ** PETexp / max_stor, 0)
        thisSMstor -= AET
        deepDrainage = np.where(thisSMstor > smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor) ** rcExp - (thisSMstor - smfc_stor), 0)
        SM_store[i+1] = min(max_stor, thisSMstor + infiltration[i] - deepDrainage)
    return SM_store / n
exInfil = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=365*20)
exPET = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1, size=365*20)
import timeit
timeit.timeit(lambda: SM_routine_f(infiltration=exInfil, PET=exPET), number=1)
```

R:

```
SM_routine_f = function(infiltration = NA, PET = NA, 
    rcScl = 0.1,    # water retention curve scalar
    rcExp = 1.3,    # water retention curve exponent
    PETexp = 2,     # exponent of PET decay
    Zr = 1000,      # root depth
    n = 0.5,        # soil porosity
    smhp = 0.00,    # soil moisture at hydroscopic point
    smwp = 0.10,    # soil moisture at wilting point
    smfc = 0.25,    # soil moisture field capacity
    s0 = .5)    # initial soil moisture 
    {
    nt = length(infiltration)
    SM_store = c(s0, rep(NA, nt))
    smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
    smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
    smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
    max_stor = Zr * n
    
    for(i in 1:length(infiltration))    {
        thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
        AET = ifelse(thisSMstor > smhp_stor, 
            min(thisSMstor - smhp_stor, PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ^ PETexp),
            0)
        thisSMstor = thisSMstor - AET
        
        deepDrainage = ifelse(thisSMstor > smfc_stor,
            min(thisSMstor - smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor)^rcExp),
            0)
        
        SM_store[i+1] = min(max_stor, thisSMstor - min(c(thisSMstor, deepDrainage)) + infiltration[i]) 
        }
    return(SM_store / n)
    }

    # generating dummy data for testing, e.g. 20 years of climate data
exInfil = rnorm(365*20, mean=1, sd=1)
exPET = rnorm(365*20, mean=2, sd=1)

    # benchmarking
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(SM_routine_f(infiltration=exInfil, PET = exPET))
```

Julia:

```
function SM_routine_f(infiltration::Vector{Float64}, PET::Vector{Float64})

rcScl = 0.1
rcExp = 1.3
PETexp = 2
Zr = 1000.0
n = 0.5
smhp = 0.00
smwp = 0.10
smfc = 0.25
s0 = 0.5
nt = length(infiltration)
SM_store = [s0; fill(missing,nt)]
smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
max_stor = Zr * n

for i in 1:length(infiltration)
    thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
    AET = (thisSMstor > smhp_stor) ? min(thisSMstor - smhp_stor, PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ^ PETexp) : 0
    thisSMstor = thisSMstor - AET
    deepDrainage = (thisSMstor > smfc_stor) ?  min(thisSMstor - smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor)^rcExp) : 0
    SM_store[i+1] = min(max_stor, thisSMstor - min(thisSMstor, deepDrainage) + infiltration[i])
end
return(SM_store / n)
end

using Distributions, BenchmarkTools
exInfiltration = rand(Normal(1, 1), 365*20);
exPET = rand(Normal(1, 2), 365*20);
@benchmark SM_routine_f($exInfiltration, $exPET)
```

Comment: If you want to continue with R, I recommend implementing this simple for loop with Rcpp. That should be pretty straightforward and easy.

Comment: In the Python lines that use `np.where`, aren't all the variables scalars? If so, what happens if you use an `if..else` structure without numpy?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Why are you using `np.where(condition, a, b)` instead of `a if condition else b`?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to see how to write minimal examples that help to boil down your core problem. With regards to your actual problem: Julia is a JIT compiled language, Python and R are not (in their standard form). As you looping over a long for loop, I'd always expect Julia to be significantly faster.

Comment: @maxxilian R has had JIT enabled by default since version 3.4.0 (released April 2017). You [can see it mentioned in the release notes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000612.html).

Comment: Thanks slothrop and Dima Chubarov, this does indeed improve performance to 70 ms. Still, though, Python is slowest on my machine though

Comment: Looks like you could make the Python code 20x faster by not doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks @KellyBundy I would love to see what that would be. A couple folks above gave advice regarding np.where() --> a if condition else b, and that generated a substantial improvement (~ 25%) but my Python is still 140x slower than my Julia (and I'm not very good with Julia). I would love to see a 20x improvement, but I'm not sure what could be implemented to generate that effect

Comment: Thanks @Roland I've not used Rcpp directly before, but I'll give that a try and post results

Comment: Similar to the Python comments, you can speed up your R code about 3x by replacing `ifelse()` (which is intended for vectors) with `if() {} else{}`, which only does length-one comparisons like you have here.

Comment: Thanks Gregor Thomas, good call on ifelse() not being optimal in this situation. It does indeed result in a 3x improvement. including all the Python and R updates gets me to: Python (6 ms), R (16 ms), Julia (0.5 ms). Much appreciated!

Comment: Just curious: "in order of popularity" increasing or decreasing? I.e., which one is most popular?

Comment: @KellyBundy Python is by far the most popular, R is a distant second (mostly myself and a couple other people), and Julia is something that a few of us are playing with but none of us count as our "preferred" language

Comment: @GregorThomas Python is also JIT compiled in that sense (and has been for a long time), but that’s not the sense in which Julia is JIT compiled: Julia compiles code to *native machine code* that is executed directly by the CPU. By contrast, both Python and R JIT compilation yields byte code that’s interpreted by a VM at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

It's bad to work with NumPy data types like that. If I convert the input arrays to Python lists of Python floats, do the work without NumPy, and convert back to a NumPy array at the end, it's about 20 times faster. Three attempts:

```
original  94.9 ms
improved   4.4 ms
original  95.1 ms
improved   4.4 ms
original  93.2 ms
improved   4.5 ms
```

Further improvement by avoiding Python's slow `min` function makes it about 30 times faster:

```
original  91.4 ms
improved   3.3 ms
original  99.4 ms
improved   3.3 ms
original  96.7 ms
improved   3.2 ms
```

Some [micro-optimizations](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=5VbNattAEL7rKfYWKZEV2WlCMVWh0Bx6SCmkpxhhNvJuLJB2t7vrJE7Ik_SSS3svfYM-Rp-mM6sfS_5JCZRSqA9mPPON5pvRzHg-f1VLO5fi8fHLwvLBy5_ed65lSWxestySvFRS2_qX5yzGUpsbm2emsZaMihD0M3ZdQaRimlqpW3e9sPOQCGmnFSCTRcEym0vRPmTGPi1YZc0t01bKorVpphi1Xv3LLE0jikWploQaIpTnzRhHBy2v2czPBc8LCywgRvJeChaSD6cfa0ln51mRxNEQxdNblQyjI2dnII9CcqGTYRzHwBhAx5BaOVcgocaUNygOncgzEEcIiBEYjD0Cn25okvR-RlYWUDs_cEAICHb47quFBW3BRC-HynR-NjVQVwaACaaSkn3iC3sw7JsncQoIEzslkndqUF1ocEBFbblZt9w0Fp6tWXjmLCW97RmE03J815Ap0VRcMWBUlwI_dp6b87Pap2WYpy3gjSuD38ENVqQDiAEVAjym2sEctlQAsl-_vI6W5Lwb-nWnDqwwjMTbCA4SZNNaZoypt5rmgl5hyV3bAI2OwzqntnCOlGsuyGY9txazybGp-zrHUgGBDvag11dYnkGPbuu5qvjBELuiW59WfuUCuJggrLeaUBHVmi79Rld1m2Z2ocUKeAjN4LHbd8ir8oJumMkyElKXtPALmSUwcSajBXNCfseSo5Pj_VEcgF81DVu9Rru83MxLBesJtP_D0Js4_WtD3RvcepngoCtmQ0wQ5_0uVz7kEvYS7gz_ziFcQTZH8IlVALGfuQeeoFKXYyeVzYHDWf7jWyBo4-MAPoPNztSa3J941kZ5mi6LqFJMzDpkN7rwH94H8O7hrsAB3HoI1GyqteBCBJ5mZlGgy449ss1H6VxY329cE1LFDSJaFD68UI8vBNxHKxrh6umeh9cUGu_5mExSN1NumJzTg9tpeGQZn9eTZBE9wc4fsiOHt4g3cAIBW_e4CU-Dyfg4Tbuvgu_d423mWxOMT6IRfyA_vpF7d6g53QunKw3ZA8bw1OnqLxxWYR28T6_zv44d6e5Cv6Dl5YyOCf9t5UI82S4ZrNpV1zf8284LKjbrQauiN5UJCY-mU0FLNp0G1e1an7DNKfsL) can speed it up some more:

```
  3.11 ± 0.03 ms  improved
  2.58 ± 0.02 ms  optimized
```

Code for original, improved, comparison and benchmark:

```py
import numpy as np

def original(infiltration=None, PET=None, rcScl=0.1, rcExp=1.3, PETexp=2, Zr=1000, n=0.5, smhp=0.00, smwp=0.10, smfc=0.25, s0=0.5):
    nt = len(infiltration)
    SM_store = np.empty(nt+1)
    SM_store[0] = s0
    smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
    smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
    smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
    max_stor = Zr * n
    for i in range(nt):
        thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
        AET = np.where(thisSMstor > smhp_stor, (thisSMstor - smhp_stor) * PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ** PETexp / max_stor, 0)
        thisSMstor -= AET
        deepDrainage = np.where(thisSMstor > smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor) ** rcExp - (thisSMstor - smfc_stor), 0)
        SM_store[i+1] = min(max_stor, thisSMstor + infiltration[i] - deepDrainage)
    return SM_store / n
exInfil = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=365*20)
exPET = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1, size=365*20)

def improved(infiltration=None, PET=None, rcScl=0.1, rcExp=1.3, PETexp=2, Zr=1000, n=0.5, smhp=0.00, smwp=0.10, smfc=0.25, s0=0.5):
    infiltration = infiltration.tolist()
    PET = PET.tolist()
    nt = len(infiltration)
    SM_store = [None] * (nt+1)
    SM_store[0] = s0
    smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
    smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
    smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
    max_stor = Zr * n
    for i in range(nt):
        thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
        AET = (thisSMstor - smhp_stor) * PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ** PETexp / max_stor if thisSMstor > smhp_stor else 0
        thisSMstor -= AET
        deepDrainage = rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor) ** rcExp - (thisSMstor - smfc_stor) if thisSMstor > smfc_stor else 0
        tmp = thisSMstor + infiltration[i] - deepDrainage
        SM_store[i+1] = max_stor if max_stor < tmp else tmp
    SM_store = np.array(SM_store)
    return SM_store / n

exInfil = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=365*20)
exPET = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1, size=365*20)

expect = original(infiltration=exInfil, PET=exPET)
result = improved(infiltration=exInfil, PET=exPET)
print((result == expect).all())

import timeit
for f in [original, improved] * 3:
    t = min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f(infiltration=exInfil, PET=exPET), number=1))
    print(f.__name__, f'{t * 1e3: 5.1f} ms')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=3VbNbtNAEL6iPMXcareOaycKQhFGQqIHDkWV2lOrKto6s81K3rW13pAExJNw6QUegMfhaZhd_8QJDlCpAgkfosn8eL75-db7-WuxMYtcPTx8WRo-fPH92Tchi1wbUEtZbICVoIrBYI4cci3uhWKZJxQXmdHMiFwl73KFAVycXdWSTi_TLInC2Ipn6yKJw7GzI8mjAK51EkdRFIAip0kApVwUJFlNKVdWjJ3IUxJH1iGyjv50APQoAwlkqHYw-M50eT4rTa6RHFQRoizMxlPmJN613kS35FBGTmlzOzWprjUcO0VtWe1bVo2Fp3sWnjqLZOsdg3JaTgoBQoFm6h4JUV2JfcxClJfndUyLUNy2Dq_PrqpyVgvU6HX8X23BB9A1DLcGn0BQ4-mFJHR9Tlus5HJcD6ejDSDy-0AOE4uotcwRizea0U7c4y9g1v2qV4OgdOz7uFpvB8wtEFW0X1_js4Nz27-T2M5YCuVtC-q84QS6y2O7M9wppXqlRrPUartVpzRPXL-1kVWtNM95LkOVa0mcyPI0oZUvU5ahE8QHTMbPJ8cjgojri2aQP0eNDkU50hEZdf4e5_-SdN3UVEX3b2jyTJTGq3pWVUm_u-o_I-2NLcVt6v_B2qcmJQgO_QcAYFYiRI9n7JMTsgdj0_d9jLIgAI9g5WGed_rTyi9dApeThJ7vA9OabbxGd5jyf5vzNHNMLV_6v7Y1mor7LoU_0FguMxvSf1b0hRRaKON5TWQCVVo_ZFnm-QSjvgMYIVGYgWUDt2y4aVAFbTK7xuOKHKY-dauoUGOBzHgZk3dzNgX-W1iBvXPcIZ1VfjWQCiYPZzPFJM5mAfCjj4YSxjiewiSM-SeQ5ZFfXV3qG0xzk_kB)

Comment: Thanks @kellybundy! This is very interesting, I never would have guessed that replacing min() with an if / else statement would improve performance so drastically. Running all code on the same machine, including all the Python and R updates,  I'm now getting the following: Python (6 ms), R (16 ms), Julia (0.5 ms). This is much more in line with what I was expecting

Comment: @ArikTashie The 6 ms is with which version? And what Python version are you using? (I used Python 3.11.4)

Comment: I'm using 3.11.5 for Python 4.3.1 for R, and 1.9.3 for Julia. 6 ms is the mean of 1000 runs using the improved version and the min is 3.6 ms (for my original bad code, the min is 70.0 ms, mean is 93). And I recognize now that using the min is better than the mean, so the current minimum values are: Python (3.6 ms), R (13.8 ms), Julia (0.4 ms). And I'm running everything in a Jupyter notebook in AWS SageMaker Studio on the same instance type (ml.t3.medium). And thanks again, @KellyBundy I'm learning a lot from your insights!

Comment: @ArikTashie Yeah, min of the times is recommended, as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat). My script measuring the `optimized` solution does use mean+stdev, but only of the fastest 5 of 100 runs. That has been working well for me, it's almost min, but seeing a small stdev still gives me confidence that it's not a complete single outlier and that I got a stable run of the script (particularly valuable since I'm usually running it on a shared web service).

Comment: Oh, sorry, and for the optimized code, I'm getting 3.05 ms. So Python Improved (3.6 ms), Python Optimized (3.05 ms), R (13.8 ms), and Julia (0.4 ms). And thanks for the extra info + link, that's useful

Comment: And incorporating GKi's recommendations for Julia (in a thread in different comment), the current results are: Python Improved (3.6 ms), Python Optimized (3.05 ms), R (12.1 ms), and Julia Original (0.4 ms), Julia Improved (0.31 ms), Julia Optimized (0.23 ms)

Answer (score 6):

An "R" version using RCPP.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rcpp(NumericVector infiltration,
                                      NumericVector PET) {
  double rcScl = 0.1;
  double rcExp = 1.3;
  double PETexp = 2;
  double Zr = 1000.0;
  double n = 0.5;
  double smhp = 0.00;
  double smwp = 0.10;
  double smfc = 0.25;
  double s0 = 0.5;
  size_t nt = infiltration.size();
  NumericVector SM_store(no_init(nt+1));
  SM_store[0] = s0;
  double smhp_stor = Zr * smhp;
  double smwp_stor = Zr * smwp;
  double smfc_stor = Zr * smfc;
  double max_stor = Zr * n;
  for(size_t i=0; i<nt; ++i) {
    double thisSMstor = SM_store[i];
    if(thisSMstor > smhp_stor) thisSMstor -= std::min(thisSMstor - smhp_stor,
                    PET[i] * pow(thisSMstor / max_stor, PETexp));
    double deepDrainage = (thisSMstor > smfc_stor) ?  std::min(thisSMstor - smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * pow(thisSMstor / smfc_stor, rcExp)) : 0;
    SM_store[i+1] = std::min(max_stor, thisSMstor - std::min(thisSMstor, deepDrainage) + infiltration[i]);
  }
  return SM_store;
}
)")

RNGkind('Mersenne-Twister', 'Inversion', 'Rejection')
set.seed(42)
exInfil = rnorm(365*20, mean=1, sd=1)
exPET = rnorm(365*20, mean=2, sd=1)
bench::mark(rcpp(exInfil, exPET))
#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr>    <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 rcpp(exInfil… 284µs  305µs     3318.    59.6KB     2.01  1649     1      497ms
```

On my PC it takes **0.305ms** but in fact this is then in C++.

A slightly changed Julia version:

```
function SM_routine_fB(infiltration::Vector{Float64}, PET::Vector{Float64})
  rcScl = 0.1
  rcExp = 1.3
  PETexp = 2
  Zr = 1000.0
  n = 0.5
  smhp = 0.00
  smwp = 0.10
  smfc = 0.25
  s0 = 0.5
  nt = length(infiltration)
  SM_store = Vector{Float64}(undef, nt+1)
  SM_store[1] = s0
  smhp_stor = Zr * smhp
  smwp_stor = Zr * smwp
  smfc_stor = Zr * smfc
  max_stor = Zr * n
  @fastmath for i in 1:nt
    thisSMstor = SM_store[i]
    if thisSMstor > smhp_stor
      thisSMstor -= min(thisSMstor - smhp_stor, PET[i] * (thisSMstor / max_stor) ^ PETexp)
    end
    deepDrainage = (thisSMstor > smfc_stor) ?  min(thisSMstor - smfc_stor, rcScl * thisSMstor * (thisSMstor / smfc_stor)^rcExp) : 0
    SM_store[i+1] = min(max_stor, thisSMstor - min(thisSMstor, deepDrainage) + infiltration[i])
  end
  return(SM_store / n)
end

using Distributions, BenchmarkTools
exInfiltration = rand(Normal(1, 1), 365*20);
exPET = rand(Normal(1, 2), 365*20);
@benchmark SM_routine_fB($exInfiltration, $exPET)
#BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
# Range (min … max):  348.894 μs …  1.257 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 60.58%
# Time  (median):     369.202 μs              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
# Time  (mean ± σ):   379.450 μs ± 41.742 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.39% ±  2.93%
#
#  █   ▆▇▂▁▂█▇▃▃▃▃▆▃▃▄▃▄▃▃▂▂▂▂▁▁▁▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▂▂▁▁▁▁               ▂
#  █▇▇▅███████████████████████████████████████████████▇█▇▆▆▆▆▆▆ █
#  349 μs        Histogram: log(frequency) by time       470 μs <
#
# Memory estimate: 114.22 KiB, allocs estimate: 4.
```

What is **0.369ms** in Julia.

Comment: Note that Julia matches the C++ if you add `@fastmath` to the loop (i.e. `@fastmath for i in 1:nt`)

Comment: Thanks @GKi! I see a ~ 10% improvement from changing 'SM_store = [s0; fill(missing,nt)]' to 'SM_store = Vector{Float64}(undef, nt+1)' and the if statement for updating thisSMstor. And then an additional 20% improvement from @fastmath. Is there any reason ever not to use @fastmath? In any case, I currently have on my machine: Python Improved (3.6 ms), Python Optimized (3.05 ms), R (12.1 ms), and Julia Original (0.4 ms), Julia Improved (0.31 ms). I'm having an issue with dependencies when trying to run Rcpp, but will update that when I get it fixed.

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-annotations gives: *Use @fastmath to allow floating point optimizations that are correct for real numbers, but lead to differences for IEEE numbers.*

Answer (score 4):

In general 10x-100x is about what to expect when comparing Julia (or other fast languages) to Python/R. Typically R is closer to the 100x side of this and python is often in the ~40x range although recent improvements in Python 3.12 bring modest (25% or so) speedups to python.

Comment: Unless you can use NumPy properly to spend most of your CPU time inside loops in pre-compiled NumPy functions, not in CPython interpreter overhead from stuff like looping 1 element at a time.  Yes, if you do that, yeah about 100x is the right order of magnitude for the slow CPython interpreter vs. things that JIT or ahead-of-time compile to native code with a decent optimizer.

Comment: After solely replacing the bad NumPy usage with just Python (see my `improved` version), Julia seems only about 10x faster. And with further optimizations only about 5x faster (estimated, I can't actually run Julia myself). Can the Julia code be much improved as well, so that it's about 100x faster than my Python code? Also @PeterCordes

Comment: @KellyBundy: Unfortunately Julia is a language I haven't played around with, and I haven't really looked at what computation the OP is doing. :/

Comment: You are correct. Throwing a `@fastmath` on the loop brings the time down to ~350ms. (back to ~10x over optimized python)

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this. (a) it's not really an answer--feels like it should be a comment, and (b) the other answers show Julia at about 10x  faster, not 100x, so it's off by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @KellyBundy also worth noting that the same trick you use in the optimized version bring the julia time down to 250 ms.